# Multiple 1D plots in a 3D plot

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

I have a 2D equation, for example `y = sin(x + t)`.  For each unique value of `t`, I would like to plot a 1D realization of `y`.  For example, if `x = 0:0.1:2*pi` and `t = 1:10`, for each value of `t` I would like to plot `y = sin(x + t)` for `x = 0:0.1:2*pi`.  Basically, I would like to have lines along one direction for each value of `t`.

Is there a way I can do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like a [`waterfall`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waterfall.html) plot be beneficial for your case?  Given a vector of `x` coordinates, for each unique value of `y` (in your case `t`), it would plot a one-dimensional realization of that curve.  First, you would generate a 2D grid of coordinates `X`, `Y` where each row of `X` and `Y` together would be a vector of `x` coordinates for one realization of `y` and you'd plot all of these together in one plot.

Something like this:

```
[t,x] = meshgrid(0:0.1:2*pi, 1:10);
waterfall(t, x, sin(x + t));
view(-50, 50); % Adjust for a better view
xlabel('x'); ylabel('t'); zlabel('y'); % Add axis labels
```

We get this plot:

[image]

If you don't desire the "vertical" baselines that you see in the plot, then you can get away with using [`surf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) by specifying some additional properties to it:

```
[t,x] = meshgrid(0:0.1:2*pi, 1:10);
surf(t, x, sin(x + t), 'FaceColor', 'white', 'EdgeColor', 'interp', 'MeshStyle', 'row');
view(-50, 50); 
xlabel('x'); ylabel('t'); zlabel('y');
```

The `FaceColor` and `EdgeColor` attributes are there to mimic what you see in the `waterfall` plot.  Each visualization has a white face and the amplitude colours are interpolated.  What is important is the `MeshStyle` attribute where you want to display the edges of the plot row wise.  The default way for `mesh` is to show both rows and columns, so you'll visualize your plot in a grid like pattern, which is not what you want.  Setting `MeshStyle` to `row` will simulate the `waterfall` plot but without the vertical baselines that you see in that plot.

You'll get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't want the vertical line of the waterfall part. Do you know how to do that?